# different custom contentmenu in different nodes in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

On right clicking the node title is not returning the return value but the complete function as a title. I want only to show the what i pass in return. I am not able to understand how to solve this. Can any1 help me on this. The answer was not working as the function with parameter d was not referring to node. It giving the error as commented below the answer.

```
var content = [
            {
                title: function(d) {
             if(d.url) {
            return 'Item 1';
}
                },
                action: function(elm, d, i) {
                    window.open(d.url, '_blank');
                }
            },
            {
                title: function(d) {
            if(d.url1) {
            return 'Item 2';
}
                },
                action: function(elm, d, i) {
                        if(d.url1){
                    window.open(d.url1, '_blank');
                        }
                }
            },
            {
                title: function(d) {
            if(d.url2) {
            return 'Item 3';
}
                },
                action: function(elm, d, i) {
                    window.open(d.url2, '_blank');
                }
            }
        ];
function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }
 collapse(root);
  update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });
text = source;
  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
   var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on('contextmenu', d3.contextMenu(content))
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? (d.status ? d.status : "#f77a03") : "#fff";
    });//changed

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .style('fill',function(d) { return d.status ? d.status : "white"; })//added
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    nodeEnter.append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { img = filter_click(r);return eval(img);})
      .attr("x", "-9px")
      .attr("y", "-20px")
      .attr("width", "20px")
      .attr("height", "40px");
  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? (d.status ? d.status : "#f77a03") : "#fff"; });//changed

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style('fill',function(d) { return d.status ? d.status : "black"; })//added
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o4AZIKf5auRiZfOC2Bo3?p=preview), which is showing exactly what I am facing and here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cZ56PW5MyHLGyMrhzbUs?p=preview) in which script.js has the code which is working what I want my script to work.

I am trying to make a custom contentmenu which can be done if I am able to solve the problem described above. Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought and got lucky, The d3-content-menu.js is slightly different in both the plunker. So when I used js from this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cZ56PW5MyHLGyMrhzbUs?p=preview), I am able to make the changes as per my need. Thanks [laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3360175/laurent) for your help.

```
.html(function(d) {
            return (typeof d.title === 'string') ? d.title : d.title(data);

        })
```

This is what i think making the difference

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a fixed array for `content`, you can use a data-dependent function:

```
    var content = function(d) { 
      menu=[ {
            title: 'View Detail',
            action: function(elm, d, i) {
                window.open(d.url, '_blank');
            }
        }];
      if ("url1" in d) { 
         menu.push({
            title: 'View Map',
            action: function(elm, d, i) {
                window.open(d.url1, '_blank');
            }
        })
      }
      return menu;
    }
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'url1' in 1. This is the error msg displaying.

Comment: The code in your plunker is not the same as the one in your question. If you use `[1,2,3]` instead of your real `data` array, then obviously it's hard to tell if the relevant fields exist....

Comment: Hi, @Laurent, I am using real {data} not {[1,2,3]} but it is not referring to node at all.